# линейный односвязный список pop, push_front

Tags: c++, xcode, list

Вот уже который день страдаю погружением и изучением ООП на С++. Решил написать **односвязный список** и вроде как получилось, но есть много вопросов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно улучшить данный блок кода -

```
template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_front(T data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = new Node(data);
    }
    else
    {
        Node* current = new Node();
        current->_pNext = head->_pNext;
        head->_pNext = current;
        
        current->_data = head->_data;
        head->_data = data;
        
        Size++;
    }
}
```

Все никак не мог придумать, как более **логично/эффективно** вставить узел в начало, по этому решил просто -

1. Создавать новый узел - **current**
2. В current->_pNext присваивать адрес следующего узла из поля head->_pNext
3. Поле _data с head присваивать новому узлу
4. Аргумент **(T data)** вставлять в head

*Также не понимаю как организовать удаление узлов с конца, это нужно находить перебором адрес предпоследнего узла ?*

Comment: Поставить концепт на шаблонный параметр; передать его не по значению, скорее всего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашим головным элементом должен быть  только созданный элемент, значит head  должен указывать на него, а его следующим элементом должен быть тот, на который указывал head до добавления. А хвост остается на своем месте, и только в том случаи, когда список был пустым хвост является также головой.
Теперь напишем выше сказанное:

```
Node* current = new Node;
current->_pNext = head;    
head = current;
head->_data = data;
if (tail == nullptr)        
     tail = head;        
++size;
```

Нужно всегда обеспечивать, чтобы  `head` указывал на первый элемент, а `tail` на последний(голова и хвост), тогда, чтобы удалить последний, нужно начиная от головы найти элемент, находящийся `перед tail` и поставить `tail на него`, а тот элемент, на который указывал tail, **удалять**.